# Unexpected app crash - c# Console App

Tags: c#, exception

I have a .NET 4.0 Console App which has been compiled in Release mode, and deployed. Most of the time the app executes successfully, but on occasion, it has crashed due to an unhandled exception. The Windows Application event log contains the following:

> Application: App.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException
>   Stack: App.Program.Main(System.String[])

I read an article on MSDN that stated 'AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException' should be used to avoid unhandled exceptions, but clearly this has not worked. Please help me to identify the cause, and how to resolve. The code is as follows:

```
class Program
{
    private static ILog _logger;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

            var configFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "log4net.config");

            // Initialize Log4Net

            XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(configFile));
            _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (LoggingHelper));  

            //App Logic starts here!
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex);
        }
    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var ex = (Exception) e.ExceptionObject;
            Log(ex);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    public static void Log(Exception ex)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger?.Error(ex);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With the un-handled exception handler you should use it as a last chance to log what happened and cleanup/save anything you need to before your app terminates. Its not a way to 'avoid' the exception and continue the app. The fact that the un-handled exception made it that far is an indication that something unplanned occurred and your state is no longer as expected.

Comment: Just so I understand your comment.. Are you saying that the app crashed out is expected and there is no way to avoid this? I would really like to find a way to prevent it from happening, and given that I'm coding defensively, and using Try.. Catch everywhere I would have thought this could never happen..

Comment: This is in reference to you statement "...should be used to avoid unhandled exceptions". I did not run the app but based on what I see I would expect the exception to be occuring. Try logging to console in your unexpected handler and log the call stack. See the catch statement in the "Main" function on this site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: The most obvious mishap here is that it crashed because it can't load Log4Net :)   Fuslogvw.exe ought to be helpful.

Comment: I agree. I expect the exception is occurring on this line:  XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(configFile));  Don't get why it isn't properly handled through standard try.. catch block though

Comment: What I really would like to achieve is a fail-safe way of stopping a console application from crashing. Is there anything I'm missing that could at least help prevent??